# Admin not showing all custom post type posts and views not working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have a custom post type called *pasakumi* and for some reason in wp-admin the views (All / Published / Trash) are showing only 4 random posts, even though I have more than that. They're also not working, for example, 'Trash (1)' is showing the same 4 posts as 'All' (see gif below).
If I create a new post, it just replaces one of the 4 shown.

[image]

The following is the code from functions.php I have for the custom post type. Maybe I need to change something here?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'pasakumi' )  && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'pasakumi' );
        $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'future', 'publish' ) );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
        $query->set( 'date_query', array( array( 'after' => array( 'year' => date( 'Y' ), 'month' => date( 'n', strtotime('last month') ), ), ) ) );
    }
} );    

$args = [
        "label" => __( "Pasākumi", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "pasakumi", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_position" => 4,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-post-status",
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "custom-fields" ],
    ];
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Try disabling all plugins except the one with the CPT, does this still happen? Do you have some additional logic like a `pre_get_posts` hook in there?

Comment: @kero yes, I have pre_get_posts for the page, why would it be interfering with the admin page? (added the code in the main post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'pasakumi' )  && $query->is_main_query() ) {
```

This is great on the frontend! **And the backend!!** `pre_get_posts` works for all queries, nothing about it is exclusive to the frontend, and you can filter queries on the backend too. As a result, your date query gets applied to every single query, even the admin ones

So first, check if it's the admin, aka:

```php
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}
```

Second, you don't need to put everything inside that giant if statement, just check for the opposite and return early.

Third, this is awful for performance:

```php
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
```

Set the value high, an unrealistically high value, but never set it to `-1`. Sure it might work for you now, but what happens when the business pivots and the number of pasakumi sky rockets? Or in 10 years time after lots of posts get created? Or when there's a lot of visitors to the site?

Comment: Thanks! The return code worked. I was aware of post_per_page being -1, it's set that way just for the development process.

Comment: Set it to 500 or something silly, why give yourself extra work of going through the code hunting for `-1` values :)